# It is Possible to Iterate Views/Controls on a MAUI.NET Page?

Tags: maui

Given a Page instance I'd like to be able to iterate all the Views and enumerate the Controls on said page -- I realize that (if possible) this would need to be recursive as most pages contain nested views.

The c# iteration logic to do this is obvious however the property or method to get children of a given page/view is not.  I can see a Children property in debug at runtime that generally gives me the collection that I would need to iterate however it doesn't seem to be public.  I'm running the current release of the MAUI.NET stuff w/VS 2022.

What am I missing -- I assume it's something obvious.  If not, does anyone have a clever solution?

Cheers.

Comment: why do you need to do this?

Comment: To work around the bug where the OSK stupidly obscures Entry controls.  I found some iOS code that someone wrote works sometimes but is throwing null ref errors when used more broadly than the example app.  Likewise, I know one can iterate views  when building for iOS by using page.Content.ToPlatform() and the resulting UIView's Subviews property.  Ideally I'd like something that works across all platforms.  Additionally, (simply put) I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to enumerate a view's children.

Comment: Most views will have either a Content or a Children property

Comment: As I stated above, from what I can see Children is visible in debug but is not accessible at design time.  Content does not give you access to contained view either -- unless there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Since you haven't provided any concrete examples it's hard to way

Comment: You are looking for something called visual tree. Guys who make controls have tutorials here and there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out about a week ago and it works for my purposes.  It's also platform independent.  Hope this helps someone else as well.

```
public static View FindFocussedView(IView rootView, View defaultView)
{
    // defaultView is a hack because pickers (especially DatePicker) do not properly
    // handle or maintain focus and can cause multiple underlying controls to have
    // focus at the same time. Thus,if no control has focus OR multiple do return defaultView.
    View viewWithFocus = null;

    var elements = ((View)rootView).GetVisualTreeDescendants()
        .Where(d => ((View)d).IsFocused);
    if (elements.Any())
    {
        if (elements.Count() == 1)
            viewWithFocus = elements.First() as View;
        else
            viewWithFocus = defaultView;
    }
    else
    {
        viewWithFocus = defaultView;
    }

    return viewWithFocus;
}
```